# PHP MVC - Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning PHP: separation of concerns, MVC, functions, arrays, the works. I'm lost right now, admittedly.

I am using an existing authentication framework:

```
https://github.com/panique/huge/
// app/core/View.php 
/**
 * Class View
 * The part that handles all the output
 */
class View
{
    /**
     * simply includes (=shows) the view. this is done from the controller. In the controller, you usually say
     * $this->view->render('help/index'); to show (in this example) the view index.php in the folder help.
     * Usually the Class and the method are the same like the view, but sometimes you need to show different views.
     * @param string $filename Path of the to-be-rendered view, usually folder/file(.php)
     * @param array $data Data to be used in the view
     */
    public function render($filename, $data = null)
    {
        if ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }

        require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . '_templates/header.php';
        require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . $filename . '.php';
        require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . '_templates/footer.php';
    }
```

Above is a note to inform you about the View class.

In my IndexCotroller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->View->render('index/index', array(
            'images' => ImagesModel::getImages())
        );
    }
```

In my ImageModel:

```
class ImageModel
{
    /**
     *
     *
     */
    public static function getImages($xxx)
    {
        $xxx = "test test test";
    }
}
```

In index/index view I have:

```
<?php $this->images; ?>
```

I get an error such as:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for ImageModel::getImages(), called in IndexController.php on line 21 and defined in ImageModel.php on line 13
```

I simply want to echo a variable to test that I can get data from my model onto my index view. I am very new to PHP, certainly have bitten off more than I can chew but this challenging me and have to know.

Are my functions and arrays wacky? Flame me, but provide knowledge too?!

Comment: `<?php $this->images; ?>` should that be an echo? as it stands it seems to do nothing

Comment: `ImagesModel::getImages()` you defined the method with a parameter! But you are not passing one on this call. _Should that method be `return`ing something rather than setting `$xxx = somthing_

Comment: _I simply want to echo a variable to test that I can get data from my model onto my index view_ Replace `$xxx = "test test test";` with `return "test test test";` And at least for now, loose the parameter on that method

Comment: @RiggsFolly Honestly, I didnt plagiarise you. So for the sake of my reputation, I will kindly delete my answer. But please, do provide and answer, and I will upvote you myself.

Comment: @EddyTheDove Well if thats the case undelete your answer and I will remove my comments

Comment: Took a moment but I see now. Thank you so much. Okay I can sanely get back to the docs!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you are not returning something from `ImagesModel::getImages()` so that value won't be set. Second, you are not passing the parameter in `getImages()` but you have this in `ImageModel`. So you should return some image from `getImage()` and remove that parameter (or pass parameter value, keeping parameter) to make it work.